# Set partitioning algorithm that aligns centroids

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I have a collection of points $C := \{x_1, \ldots, x_{60 N}\}$ in 3D space.

I am looking for a partition of $P$ of $C$ with the following properties:

1. Each of $P$'s sets contains $60$ points, i.e.,
   $P = \{p_1, \ldots, p_N\}$ where $p_i = \{x_{j_1}, \ldots x_{j_{60}}\}$.
2. The set of centroids $\{c_1, \ldots, c_N\}$ where $$c_i = \frac{1}{60}\sum_{x \in p_i} x$$ all lie on the same line if possible. Otherwise $c_1, \ldots, c_N$ are such that they form "as close as a line as possible" (more formally such that the sum of their distances to the line formed by their linear regression is minimized).

Is there an efficient way of doing this?
The solution might not be unique and that's OK, I just need one solution.

---

**Motivation**

I have a 3D binary map of the contour of a medical image for which I want to create a mesh. Such a mesh is obtained by gluing many 2D layers, which all contain the same number of points, hence the question.